# Ordenar listas em dicionários em python

Tags: python-3.x, dicionário

Olá,
estou tentado ordenar meu dicionário, mas estou encontrando dificuldades.

```
dict = {'EstacaoCodigo' : ['1','2','3'] ,'NivelConsistencia' : ['0','2','1'] ,'Data' : ['01/12/1996','01/12/1999','01/12/1994'] }
```

Seria possível ordenar os valores das listas a partir da lista de datas?
O resultado esperado é:

```
{'EstacaoCodigo' : ['2','1','3'] ,'NivelConsistencia' : ['2','0','1'] ,'Data' : ['01/12/1999','01/12/1996','01/12/1994'] }
```

Comment: Primeira coisa: Chamar a variável de `dict` é uma péssima escolha. `dict` é usado internamente pelo `python` com um `type`.

Answer (score 2):

Tem - mas tem que entender os passos possíveis antes de conseguir fazer algo assim.
O método `sort` das listas (ou a função `sorted`) aceitam como parâmetro opcional uma função de "chave de ordenação".
Essa função recebe como argumento um elemento da lista que está sendo ordenada, e deve retornar um tipo de dado que quando comparado com os operadores normais (`<`, `==`, `>`) resulte na ordenação na ordem desejada.

Então, o que é necessário: ler essas datas para um formato em que elas sejam comparáveis em ordem crescente - isso pode ser ou um objeto do tipo `date` ou uma string no formato ano-mes-dia.

Agora, mesmo aplicando o `.sort` nas listas em todas os valores no dicionário, não  é possível (ou pelo menos não é prático) buscar a data correspondente em *outra* lista - já que a função `key` só vai receber como parâmetro os elementos da lista que está sendo ordenada. A solução então é, temporariamente, agregar as datas (ordenáveis) a lista que vai ser ordenada, fazer a ordenação, e extrair de volta essas datas. Se cada elemento de cada lista for uma tupla, onde o primeiro elemneto é a data correspondente, e o segundo elemento o valor original, na verdade, nem precisamos usar a função de chave: as datas sendo o primeiro elemento de cada tupla já vão ser comparadas com os pesos desejados.

Resumindo:

- extrair as datas em uma lista ordenável
- para cada lista a ordenar:

  - transformar cada elemento da lista em um par (data, elemento)
  - ordenar a lista
  - transformar cada elemento da lista de volta, descartando a data
- reintegrar a chave com as datas no dicionário

Transpondo esses 6 passos para Python temos:

```
from datetime import datetime

def ordena_por_valores_de_data(dct, chave_datas='Data'):
    datas = dct.pop(chave_datas)
    datas_ordenaveis = [datetime.strptime(data, '%d/%M/%Y') for data in datas]
    for chave, lista in dct.items():
        dct[chave] = [par for par in zip(datas_ordenaveis, lista)]
        dct[chave].sort(reverse=True)
        dct[chave] = [par[1] for par in dct[chave]]
    dct[chave_datas] = datas
```

E ao testar no modo interativo com:
   dict_ = {'EstacaoCodigo' : ['1','2','3'] ,'NivelConsistencia' : ['0','2','1'] ,'Data' : ['01/12/1996','01/12/1999','01/12/1994'] }
   ordena_por_valores_de_data(dict_)

Temos a saída:

```
{'EstacaoCodigo': ['2', '1', '3'],
 'NivelConsistencia': ['2', '0', '1'],
 'Data': ['01/12/1996', '01/12/1999', '01/12/1994']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Caso você só tenha um dicionário e queira ordernar uma lista dentro desse dicionário, pode ser utilizado [sorted](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting), como no exemplo abaixo:

```
>>> d = {'EstacaoCodigo' : ['1','2','3'] ,'NivelConsistencia' : ['0','2','1'] ,'Data' : ['01/12/1996','01/12/1999','01/12/1994'] }
>>> d['Data'] = sorted(d['Data'], reverse=True)
>>> d
{'EstacaoCodigo' : ['2','1','3'] ,'NivelConsistencia' : ['2','0','1'] ,'Data' : ['01/12/1999','01/12/1996','01/12/1994'] }
```

Caso você utilize outras maneiras e expor a data, é possível que tenha que ser alterada algumas coisas na função sorted, mas provavelmente o sorted ainda será suficiente, tendo no máximo que adicionar um valor [key](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#Key_Functions).

Comment: Deu certo, porém pela data ser uma string ( eu acho) ela ta ordenando primeiro pelo dia depois mes e depois ano. 
Agora transformei em data, mas só está ordenando a lista das datas as outras continuam na mesma forma
datetime.strptime('01/12/1999', '%d/%m/%Y')

Comment: @PauloPraça não entendi a última parte. Você quer ordernar EstacaoCodigo e NivelConsistencia também? Se sim, é só aplicar o mesmo processo `d['EstacaoCodigo'] = sorted(d['EstacaoCodigo'] )`.

Comment: Vou tentar explicar melhor.

Comment: d['EstacaoCodigo'][0] = '1'
d['Data'][0] = '01/12/1999'
quando ordenar pela data, eu queria que a posição das outras listas também fossem ordenadas junto com as datas.
Ficando assim:
d['EstacaoCodigo'][1] = '1'
d['Data'][1] = '01/12/1999'

Não sei se estou conseguindo ser claro.
Talvez eu tenha que criar outro dicionario fazendo com quem todas os valores das chaves que possuam o mesmo index estejam na mesma lista

Comment: Eu quero ordenar todos os valores das listas de acordo com a data